# Print histograms including variable name for all variables in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a simple histogram for every variable in my dataframe, which I can do using sapply below. But, how can I include the name of the variable in either the title or the x-axis so I know which one I'm looking at? (I have about 20 variables.)

Here is my current code:

```
x = # initialize dataframe
sapply(x, hist)
```

Comment: Could you make a working example that includes the definition of x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to modify your existing approach to include column name as the title of each histogram, using the `iris` dataset as an example:

```
# loop over column *names* instead of actual columns
sapply(names(iris), function(cname){
  # (make sure we only plot the numeric columns)
  if (is.numeric(iris[[cname]]))
    # use the `main` param to put column name as plot title
    print(hist(iris[[cname]], main=cname))
})
```

After you run that, you'll be able to flip through the plots with the arrows in the viewer pane (assuming you're using R Studio).

Here's an example output:
[image]

*p.s.* check out `grid::grob()`, `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`, and related functions if you want to arrange the histograms onto a single plot window and save it to a single file.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Assuming you have wide data you can transform it to long format with gather. Than a ggplot solution with geom_histogram and facet_wrap:

```
library(tidyverse)

# make wide data (20 columns)
df <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 20)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- LETTERS[1:20]

# transform to long format (2 columns)
df <- gather(df, key = "name", value = "value")

# plot histigrams per name
ggplot(df) +
  geom_histogram(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~name, ncol = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the facet_wrap suggestion. This is cool but not exactly what I was looking for.